# 7-Zip. h (Hash) command. Calculate hash values for files. When you use it?

Tags: windows, 7-zip, archiving, hashing, file-archiver

I use 7-Zip. I work in Windows 10 Home 64-bit. I use command line. From 7-Zip help I know there is h (Hash) command. Calculate hash values for files.

Syntax

h [-scrc{Method}] [files]

Supported methods: CRC32, CRC64, SHA1, SHA256, BLAKE2sp. Default method is CRC32.

In which situation you use h (Hash) command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were publishing a file online, and you published the hash with it, then people who were downloading the file could check that the hash matched. If it matches it indicates the file was not corrupted or tampered with.

Conversely, if you are downloading a file that has a published hash, such as a Linux install image, you could use 7-zip to check that the hash matches.

Comment: Thank you. I have 2000 PNG files. 19-22 kB each. I want to store them in archive. I work in Windows 10 Home 64-bit. I want to use 7-Zip archiver. It is enough for me to archive without compression. After I will make zip-file I will move it to another computer in home network. On this computer Windows 10 Home 64-bit too. On this computer archive will be stored. When I will need this PNG sequence I will make copy of zip-file to another computer. Then I will unpack PNG sequence. On this computer Windows 10 Home 64-bit too. In described scheme when it is usefull to use h command?

Comment: That comment belongs as part of the Question. That said, as @BenjiWiebe explained, calculating the hash is used to show a file has the same hash value as the original. The hash is similar to a checksum.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe. Thank you, BenjiWiebe. In scheme which I described what method to use? CRC32, CRC64, SHA1, SHA256, BLAKE2sp

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik. Thank you, DrMoishe Pippik. In scheme which I described what method to use? CRC32, CRC64, SHA1, SHA256, BLAKE2sp

Comment: Makes very little difference.

Comment: @Konskoo You could try researching the names of the hash algorithms. A full explanation of the differences and reasons they exist is out of scope of this question, or even this site.